# Django User M2M relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

When trying to syncdb with the following models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='from_user')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user_from', 'user_to'),)

User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'following' clashes with related m2m field 'User.followers'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'following'.

auth.user: Reverse query name for m2m field 'following' clashes with related m2m field 'User.followers'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'following'.
auth.user: The model User has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model Contact, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.

auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'following' clashes with related m2m field 'User.followers'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'following'.

auth.user: Reverse query name for m2m field 'following' clashes with related m2m field 'User.followers'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'following'.
```

Comment: I copied your code snippet to a test app and run syncdb and it works. I think there maybe some other details you did not mentioned here.

Comment: I have the same problem when I run test, but in Syncdb and on saving objects with the shell it works. I still need the test :-s.

Comment: I don't think you're telling us everything. Are you using an external app to enhance the User model?

Answer (score 0):

See Carl's answer to this question [Django: Model name clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036506/django-model-name-clash)