# How to mitigate related_name clash between 2 apps?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use `django-generic-ratings` and `django-reviews` together. However, they both have models named `Vote` and both these models defined a field to User with the same related name `votes`

From this similar question [Django: Model name clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036506/django-model-name-clash) , it looks like one way to mitigate this is to change the source code of one app and have it use a different related name. Is there a way to reconcile this related_name clash with code outside these 2 apps (without having to modify either apps' code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) either one of the models, but code relying on the related attribute will still break so you might want to fork the repository and change those parts, then use git upstream to keep your package up to date with the master branch in the future